# Sorting an ArrayCollection in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

Is there any way in Flex where in we can sort an arraycollection based on strings .

I have a dataprovider with  strings like "Critical" "High" "Medium" "Low"
 where in I need to sort it in such a way that I need Critical to be displayed on the top and next High , Medium and Low follows.

Can somebody let me know any logic .

Thanks,
Kumar

Answer (score 23):

`ArrayCollection` is a subclass of `ListCollectionView` that has a `sort` [property](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#sort). The `Sort` class has a `compareFunction` [property](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/collections/Sort.html#compareFunction) that you can use to define custom sort functions.

```
private function sortFunction(a:Object, b:Object, array:Array = null):int
{
   //assuming that 'level' is the name of the variable in each object 
   //that holds values like "Critical", "High" etc
   var levels:Array = ["Low", "Medium", "High", "Critical"];
   var aLevel:Number = levels.indexOf(a.level);
   var bLevel:Number = levels.indexOf(b.level);
   if(aLevel == -1 || bLevel == -1)
      throw new Error("Invalid value for criticality ");
   if(aLevel == bLevel)
      return 0;
   if(aLevel > bLevel)
      return 1;
   return -1;
}
var sort:Sort = new Sort();
sort.compareFunction = sortFunction;
arrayCollection.sort = sort;
arrayCollection.refresh();
```