# ActionScript: Sorting datagrid and getting data from specific cells programmatically

Tags: sorting, actionscript, datagrid, arraycollection

I have a datagrid in my code that looks like this:

```
<s:DataGrid id="dg">
  <s:ArrayCollection id="ac">
    <s:DataItem ../>
    <s:DataItem ../>
  </s:ArrayCollection>
</s:DatGrid>
```

I am trying to have a separate label (by default) show the data from a particular cell after sorting the data in a particular way.

For Example:

```
DataGrid shows:

Date  Type
----  ----
8     yes      
12    no
6     this
7     that

Label: 6 (First date after sorting in ascending order)
```

Any easy way I can do this in ActionScript (or otherwise)? Should I try to work with the ArrayCollection component or the DataGrid?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, using the [sorting ArrayCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602385/sorting-an-arraycollection-in-flex) reference. Used two different methods for sorting and extracting:

Sorting:

```
private function sortFunction(a:Object, b:Object, array:Array = null):int
{
  ..my sorting code..
}

public function Grid_onLoad(event:Event):void
{
  var sort:Sort = new Sort();
  sort.compareFunction = sortFunction;
  items.sort = sort;
  items.refresh();
}
```

Extraction:

```
public function FirstDate():String
{
  return items.getItemAt(0).Date;
}
```

Then its just a matter of calling the functions appropriately:

```
<s:DataGrid id="items" initialize="Grid_onLoad(event)">
  <s:ArrayCollection id="ac">
    <s:DataItem ../>
    <s:DataItem ../>
  </s:ArrayCollection>
</s:DatGrid>

<s:Label text="{FirstDate()}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look into ArrayCollection's sort feature:
[Sorting ArrayCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602385/sorting-an-arraycollection-in-flex)